# How does one populate his named tuple from an XML File?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, populate

i'm kind of Stuck

I was wondering how i should populate my tuple from an XML file.

This is what i have so far:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

class Code:
    def __init__(self, ErrorCode, Amount):
        self.ErrorCode = ErrorCode
        self.Amount = Amount


filepath = "D:\V11\Dog"

Codes = (Code('txtPLC_ERROR;A: 16', 0), Code('txtPLC_ERROR;A: 119', 0), Code('txtPLC_ERROR;B: 95', 0))


def readConfig():
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(filepath + '\Config.xml')
    itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
#    print(len(itemlist))
#    print(itemlist[0].attributes['name'].value)
    for s in itemlist:
        print("Some Profound text")
        Codes.ErrorCode += s
readConfig()
```

and now i get this error:

```
   File "..\PycharmProjects\ProjectX\Analyze.py", line 32, in readConfig
    Codes.Errorcode += s
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Errorcode'>
```

Please do not flag this question just becouse i'm stupid.

Comment: `Codes` is a tuple containing objects of class `Code`. `ErrorCode` is an attribute of `Code` and not a tuple. What does `Codes.Errorcode += s` supposed to do?

Comment: Hi! it was supposed to add an extra "ErrorCode"  to the existing tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Codes.ErrorCode += s` makes so sense. Codes is a tuple and contains objects of class Code. Now if you want to add new Code objects, you need to do something like `Codes += Code(string, error_code)`.

However, [Tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) are immutable. You cannot add/remove stuff from a tuple once it is created. You can, however, use a list.

```py
# codes is a list
Codes = [Code('txtPLC_ERROR;A: 16', 0), Code('txtPLC_ERROR;A: 119', 0), Code('txtPLC_ERROR;B: 95', 0)]

def readConfig():
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(filepath + '\Config.xml')
    itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
    for s in itemlist:
        # append a code object to codes
        Codes.append(Code(s, 0))
readConfig()
```

Comment: Why `# append a code object to codes`? Is that what the OP wants? Did he confirm it anywhere?

Comment: "I was wondering how i should populate my tuple from an XML file" - I guess.